How do I create a google_monitoring_alert_policy containing a filter checking for missing values
I'm want to create a google_monitoring_alert_policy that checks if a field is present in the LogEntry by using the :* syntax described by the docs.
But Terraform returns:

Error creating AlertPolicy: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.

The resource looks like this:
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "my-alert-policy" {
  ...
  conditions {
    ...
    condition_matched_log {
      filter = <<-EOT
        myField:*
      EOT
     ...
    }
  }
 ...
}

Using hashicorp/google version 4.84.0
I've tried to create alert policies without myField:* and that works, I've tried the query in Logs Explorer. Also works.

You could try export TF_LOG=TRACE to get detailed logging include the underlying REST calls. Using this you may be able to determine what terraform is generating that's incorrect. By the way myField:* detects presence not omission. And, if myField is undefined that is an error.

A typo from my part, thank you. I'll see what trace will give me

You're probably looking for projects.alertPoilicies.create

The trace gives me the following: "code": 400, "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT". Looking at the docs I see no mention of illegal characters or any ways of escaping. I've created other alerts, but when I add :* to them they fail

Do you not get the entire request? https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{project}/alertPolicies...? You may be able to debug|replay that to see what's going wrong. In fact, you can try to recreate the call using the page in the link I gave

Yes, got the request and it looked as expected. I also tried to create such an alert from the GCP console but it also returns a 400. So it looks like this is not supported .

I can confirm that this is not supported: See https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors#view_associated_log_entries
